# using ng-repeat to retrive data from an http response array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to retrieve a response from an HTTP request using `ng-repeat`. This is my JSON object:

```
{
  "sessid":"47",
  "value":[
    {
      "_id":"1",
      "0":"1",
      "_exportid":"47",
      "1":"47",
      "sender_id":"0",
      "2":"0",
      "receiver_id":"0",
      "3":"0",
      "sender_address":"",
      "4":"",
      "receiver_address":"",
      "5":"",
      "price_in_btc":"2",
      "6":"2",
      "price_in_curr":"3",
      "7":"3",
      "status":"1",
      "8":"1",
      "account_id":"12",
      "9":"12",
      "date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
      "10":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "_id":"2",
      "0":"2",
      "_exportid":"47",
      "1":"47",
      "sender_id":"0",
      "2":"0",
      "receiver_id":"0",
      "3":"0",
      "sender_address":"",
      "4":"",
      "receiver_address":"",
      "5":"",
      "price_in_btc":"2",
      "6":"2",
      "price_in_curr":"3",
      "7":"3",
      "status":"1",
      "8":"1",
      "account_id":"12",
      "9":"12",
      "date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
      "10":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "_id":"3",
      "0":"3",
      "_exportid":"47",
      "1":"47",
      "sender_id":"46",
      "2":"46",
      "receiver_id":"47",
      "3":"47",
      "sender_address":"4504859484",
      "4":"4504859484",
      "receiver_address":"4584958459",
      "5":"4584958459",
      "price_in_btc":"0.01",
      "6":"0.01",
      "price_in_curr":"$200",
      "7":"$200",
      "status":"0",
      "8":"0",
      "account_id":"24524",
      "9":"24524",
      "date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
      "10":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my Angular controller:

```
app.controller('transCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://localhost/bitty/class/v1/getransactions')
      .then(function (res) {
    var me = res.data.value;
    $scope.values = me;
    console.log($scope.values);
});
```

...and here is how I used my `ng-repeat`:

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="val in values">
    <td><span class="tablesaw-cell-content">1</span></td>
    <td><span class="tablesaw-cell-content">{{val.sender_address}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="tablesaw-cell-content">{{val.receiver_address}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="tablesaw-cell-content">{{val.price_in_btc}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="tablesaw-cell-content">${{val.price_in_curr}}</span></td>
    <td><span class="tablesaw-cell-content">{{val.date}}</span></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Trying this doesn't return anything on the table, I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: What is the result of `console.log($scope.values);`?

Comment: as satpal mentioned...confirm that your $scope.values has data

Comment: Change `ng-repeat="val in values">` to  `ng-repeat="val in values.value"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.js"></script>
      
    </head>
    
    <body data-ng-app="role" data-ng-controller="fooController">
     <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
        <tr class="bg-primary">
         <th>SR NO.</th>
         <th>Sender Address</th>
         <th>Reciever Address</th>
         <th>Price in BTC</th>
         <th>Price in Curr</th>
         <th>date</th>
    
                    </tr>       
    
             <tr ng-repeat="val in dataValue track by $index">
                <td><span class="tablesaw-cell-content">1</span></td>
                <td><span class="tablesaw-cell-content">{{val.sender_address}}</span></td>
                <td><span class="tablesaw-cell-content">{{val.receiver_address}}</span></td>
                <td><span class="tablesaw-cell-content">{{val.price_in_btc}}</span></td>
                <td><span class="tablesaw-cell-content">{{val.price_in_curr}}</span></td>
                <td><span class="tablesaw-cell-content">{{val.date}}</span></td>
    
           </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    
    </html> 
    
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('role', []);
    
    app.controller('fooController', function($scope){
    $scope.data = {
      "sessid":"47",
      "value":[
        {
          "_id":"1",
          "0":"1",
          "_exportid":"47",
          "1":"47",
          "sender_id":"0",
          "2":"0",
          "receiver_id":"0",
          "3":"0",
          "sender_address":"My Address",
          "4":"",
          "receiver_address":"",
          "5":"",
          "price_in_btc":"2",
          "6":"2",
          "price_in_curr":"3",
          "7":"3",
          "status":"1",
          "8":"1",
          "account_id":"12",
          "9":"12",
          "date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
          "10":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        },
        {
          "_id":"2",
          "0":"2",
          "_exportid":"47",
          "1":"47",
          "sender_id":"0",
          "2":"0",
          "receiver_id":"0",
          "3":"0",
          "sender_address":"My Address",
          "4":"",
          "receiver_address":"My receiver Address",
          "5":"",
          "price_in_btc":"2",
          "6":"2",
          "price_in_curr":"3",
          "7":"3",
          "status":"1",
          "8":"1",
          "account_id":"12",
          "9":"12",
          "date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
          "10":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        },
        {
          "_id":"3",
          "0":"3",
          "_exportid":"47",
          "1":"47",
          "sender_id":"46",
          "2":"46",
          "receiver_id":"47",
          "3":"47",
          "sender_address":"4504859484",
          "4":"4504859484",
          "receiver_address":"4584958459",
          "5":"4584958459",
          "price_in_btc":"0.01",
          "6":"0.01",
          "price_in_curr":"$200",
          "7":"$200",
          "status":"0",
          "8":"0",
          "account_id":"24524",
          "9":"24524",
          "date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
          "10":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        }
      ]
    }
    $scope.dataValue = $scope.data.value;
    
    });
    </script>
    </html>
```

Working Demo

Answer (score 0):

Try `var me = JSON.parse(res.data.value);`

or `var me = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.data.value));`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure basics first, variable name, app name, controller name etc because as you say if you are getting values it should be printed with this code.

I've just put your code and data in this plunker.
The js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
   data = {
  "sessid":"47",
  "value":[
    {
      "_id":"1",
      "0":"1",
      "_exportid":"47",
      "1":"47",
      "sender_id":"0",
      "2":"0",
      "receiver_id":"0",
      "3":"0",
      "sender_address":"",
      "4":"",
      "receiver_address":"",
      "5":"",
      "price_in_btc":"2",
      "6":"2",
      "price_in_curr":"3",
      "7":"3",
      "status":"1",
      "8":"1",
      "account_id":"12",
      "9":"12",
      "date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
      "10":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "_id":"2",
      "0":"2",
      "_exportid":"47",
      "1":"47",
      "sender_id":"0",
      "2":"0",
      "receiver_id":"0",
      "3":"0",
      "sender_address":"",
      "4":"",
      "receiver_address":"",
      "5":"",
      "price_in_btc":"2",
      "6":"2",
      "price_in_curr":"3",
      "7":"3",
      "status":"1",
      "8":"1",
      "account_id":"12",
      "9":"12",
      "date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
      "10":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "_id":"3",
      "0":"3",
      "_exportid":"47",
      "1":"47",
      "sender_id":"46",
      "2":"46",
      "receiver_id":"47",
      "3":"47",
      "sender_address":"4504859484",
      "4":"4504859484",
      "receiver_address":"4584958459",
      "5":"4584958459",
      "price_in_btc":"0.01",
      "6":"0.01",
      "price_in_curr":"$200",
      "7":"$200",
      "status":"0",
      "8":"0",
      "account_id":"24524",
      "9":"24524",
      "date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
      "10":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    }
  ]
}
$scope.values = data.value
});
```

Html :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/latest/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller ="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="val in values">

            <td><span class="tablesaw-cell-content">1</span></td>
            <td><span class="tablesaw-cell-content">{{val.sender_address}}</span></td>
            <td><span class="tablesaw-cell-content">{{val.receiver_address}}</span></td>
            <td><span class="tablesaw-cell-content">{{val.price_in_btc}}</span></td>
            <td><span class="tablesaw-cell-content">${{val.price_in_curr}}</span></td>
            <td><span class="tablesaw-cell-content">{{val.date}}</span></td>

       </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Working Plunker :- https://plnkr.co/edit/pEBpOzcyjV5iTaaIURW6?p=preview